# Storing objects in a vector at the time of construction

Tags: c++, object, constructor, stdvector

I'm writing a module for a project and I want the interface be as simple as possible. I want to store the objects in a vector as they are constructed.
Namely this is simply what I have been trying with many different ways using methods and standalone functions, using static declarations whatsoever, but none worked;

```
vector<trialclass> vektor;
class trialclass {
public:
    trialclass() {
        vektor.push_back(*this);
    }
}
```

Thanks very much

Comment: You *do* realise that `vektor.push_back(*this);` is pushing a *copy* rather than the current instance right?

Comment: Can you explain what you've tried, what results you got, what results you expected please?  "none worked" doesn't give us a lot to go on. A complete example program that demonstrates your problem would be a big help.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? What problem are you trying to solve? It seems like a bad idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it stands you code doesn't compile. First the class needs a semicolon at the end

```
vector<trialclass> vektor;
class trialclass {
public:
    trialclass() {
        vektor.push_back(*this);
    }
};
^^^
```

Second, the declaration of `vektor` doesn't know what a `trialclass` is.
This rearrangement gets around the problem

```
class trialclass {
public:
    trialclass();
};

std::vector<trialclass> vektor;

trialclass::trialclass() {
    vektor.push_back(*this);
}
```

This compiles and "works" in the sense that `vektor` ends up with a item in for each `trialclass` constructed, but note these are copies of the `trialclass`

Comment: thank you very much. But as Nim pointed out, this results in a copy of the object. How do I create a pointer to the object in the vector or is it possible to construct the object directly inside the vector?

Comment: You can do emplace_back in C++11, but not inside the contructor since emplace_back calls the constructor for you. Why are you trying to do this? What are you really trying to achieve? As @AlanSokes said, this is probably a bad idea.

Comment: @BerkerPeköz What are you intending on doing with the vektor?

Comment: This is a real-time scheduling module, and there will be deadlines changing all the time etc. The idea is to create an object(tasks actually) inside a vector **that will be used like a queue**, and to create an interface as simple as possible so that the project engineers will spend minimal energy integrating my module. I also need to change the member values such as deadlines of the objects. This doesn't have to happen in a constructor or even a method, but the interface has be simple to the customer.

Comment: I'm new at cxx thus it may be wonderful if you say so:) I'll make a research on shared pointers then, or if it's easy to you you can explain it simply, but I've already taken your time a lot :)

Comment: I have solved my problem, so a final comment: I have created a vector of pointer to trialclass and solved the issue without using shared pointers. simply replaced with vector<trialclass*> and vektor.push_back(this); thanks everyone!